# Convert hours:minutes AM/PM to unix timestamp

Tags: java, android, unix, android-studio

I'm from PHP background but learning Android, so please excuse me if this is too basic.

I have three variables which contain hours, minutes, and am/pm. How would I convert it to a unix timestamp so that I get the combined value in seconds?

```
String hours = String.valueOf(hourBox.getText()); // may contain a value like 05
String minutes = String.valueOf(minuteBox.getText()); // may contain a value like 45
String ampm = String.valueOf(ampmBox.getText()); // may contain a value like PM or AM

// PHP way
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d '.$hours.':'.$minutes.' '.$ampm);
echo strtotime($timestamp);

// What would be the equivalent of this in Java?
```

Comment: use calendar class of java. You can add hours, minutes, seconds easily or use simpledateformat

Comment: @HRaval FYI, the `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use LocalDateTime for that:

```
    String hours = "05";
    String minutes = "45";
    String ampm = "PM";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd hh:mm a");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(String.format("20160101 %s:%s %s", hours, minutes, ampm), formatter);

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

In case you don't have LocalDateTime yet, you can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
    String hours = "05";
    String minutes = "45";
    String ampm = "PM";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    Date dateTime = format.parse(String.format("%s:%s %s", hours, minutes, ampm));

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

As you see, the code is pretty much the same.

If you want to keep the current date, switch to Calendar:

```
    String hours = "05";
    String minutes = "45";
    String ampm = "PM";

    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hours));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, "AM".equals(ampm) ? 0 : 1);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");

    System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` for some reason isn't available in my version of Android Studio

Comment: I added Java7 version for you. Also, please see @Basil Bourque answer.

Comment: But that would take the month date and year as Jan 1, 1970. Can that not be set to current month, year and day?

Comment: I also added you an example with calendar, that will keep the current date. Enjoy!

Comment: Yeh, I had it figured it out anyway. Thanks for solution though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Soshin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057297/642706) is good. But personally I would work with the date and the time separately.

## `LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20160101" , dateFormatter );
```

## `LocalTime`

And the time-of-day. No need for the AM/PM part; the formatting code indicates whether the expected time-of-day is in 12-hour time or 24-hour time.

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hhmm" );  // hh = two digits of 12-hour time (1-12). mm = minute-of-hour.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( hours + minutes , timeFormatter );  // 0545 in afternoon.
```

## `LocalDateTime`

You can combine them into a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain the intended time zone of this value, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

A `LocalDateTime` has no meaning; it is not an actual moment without the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. A `ZonedDateTime` in contrast is indeed an actual point on the timeline.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: `LocalDate` for some reason isn't available in my version of Android Studio